# How can I force syslog traffic to use TCP instead of UDP?

Tags: linux, centos, syslog, syslogd

Centos 5.x

I'd like to have my syslog traffic use TCP instead of UDP.

Does the stock syslog daemon for CentOS support this?  If so, where would I set that option?

-M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe tht the stock syslog daemon on Centos5 does not support this. Also note that port 514/tcp was reserved for 'shell' access, but I think that is deprecated going forward.

Check out [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/), which has become the default syslog daemon in Ubuntu and [RedHat 6 beta](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6-Beta/html/Beta_2_Release_Notes/apcs04.html) (and Centos 6). It can [read your existing syslog.conf](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html) without any changes, and can also be extended quiet a bit. It also supports [syslog over tcp](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/features.html).

I found that  syslog-ng is better documented and has more community examples. However, the syntax for rsyslog.conf is more similar to the syntax of syslog.conf . If you use syslog-ng, then feel free to stick with syslog-ng. If you have some existing syslog.conf's, then check out rsyslog.

On my Ubuntu system, I dropped in my old syslog.conf into /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf and it worked right away. Later, I was able to add several of my own features, such as storing remote syslogs at /var/log/syslogs/$REMOTE_HOST/$FACILITY.log.

---

Update 20110524:

For more information on this, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5426 , which specifically [recommends syslog over TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5426#section-4.3).

Answer (score 3):

It may be worthwhile to take a look at syslog-ng which does support TCP (and is a better solution overall).

http://freshmeat.net/projects/syslog-ng/

Comment: Thanks. Yea from what I could find out online, the stock syslogd just doesn't support it period.  How does rsyslog compare to syslog-ng?

Comment: I prefer rsyslogd, and there's a comparisson on rsyslogd site: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_ng_comparison.html